# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser extract links that include a keyword

Tags: php, parsing, dom

Im trying to extract few links from url using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, only links that include "HOROSKOPI_CATEGORY" on it, something like this:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://www.ikub.al/Horoskopi/Default.aspx');

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
?>
```

but this is extracting all url links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need filter your href attribute like:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://www.ikub.al/Horoskopi/Default.aspx');

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
 if(strpos($element->href, "Horoskopi"))
       echo "http://www.ikub.al/Horoskopi/".$element->href . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you, is working but extracting only url like "/sdfsaf.aspx" not full url, is easy tu echo full href?

Comment: your code is echo: ../HOROSKOPI_CATEGORY/1311280074/Article-Miu.aspx
not full url